# undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init'

Tags: c++, ubuntu

HI,

I have an error: undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init'`. I have the encryption code in the `header.cpp`. In `header.h` i've initialized the method that i use for encryption. i've created an `ar lib.a` from `header.cpp and header.h`. i've added the `-lcrypto` but still when i run the test.cpp code where i've added in the header the header.h and i compile `g++ test.cpp -o test -lib.a` i have this error. where am i wrong?

```
the compilation code:
g++ -c -static -L -lb header.cpp -lcrypto -o lib.o
ar rcs lib.a lib.o
g++ test.cpp -o tst libr.a
```

in the `header.h` i did include all the libraries necesarry for the `openssl/evp.h` and so on. In `test.cpp` i've included `header.h file`.

Comment: I am not sure from your description if you tried g++ test.cpp -o tst libr.a `-lcrypto`

Comment: When building a static library no dependencies on external libraries are recorded. So most likely moving `-lcrypto` to the final compilation will help.